# Purethermal2 + RPi4 (4GB + Raspbian)

Tags: pi-4, raspbian-buster

A week ago I received a fresh RPi4 4GB and started to play with it. I installed Raspbian Buster from the downloads page, no errors.

After everything was set up, I tried to connect my Purethermal 2 (https://groupgets.com/manufacturers/getlab/products/purethermal-2-flir-lepton-smart-i-o-module) with a Flir Lepton 3.5 module. But, until now, I've been unable to obtain a simple frame.

I had a similar set up working perfectly on a RPi3 B+ with the same Purethermal board running for weeks with no errors. But with the RPi4, every time I try to obtain a frame from the camera I get the same error:

```
usb 1-1.3: Not enough bandwidth for new device state.
usb 1-1.3: Not enough bandwidth for altsetting 1
```

I've connected the board to a USB2 port, error. Same when I connect it to a USB3 port.

The board is getting detected because I can see it in dmesg, but a strange behaviour happens: it created two
/dev/video
devices, while it only creates one in the RPi3 B+. One of the two is totally empty when using

v4l2-ctl -d<> --list-controls

while the other one reports everything as in the other RPi model.

I don't know what else to do. I've also opened an issue on their repository with the problem, because I don't know which is the source of the problem at all.

Any help will be appreciated!